# What is the IP Network range for Google Cloud Storage service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to retrieve the IP ranges used by the GCP Storage service?  When I `dig storage.googleapis.com` I get a list of IPs that is not included in the range present [here](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json).

My scenario:
I'm accessing a Google Cloud Storage bucket from an AWS network. I have an outbound rule in the AWS security group that allows connections to specific IP ranges. I need to include there the IP ranges for GCP Storage. Is there a similar concept in GCP to [S3 managed prefix lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-aws-managed-prefix-lists.html#available-aws-managed-prefix-lists)?

Answer (score 1):

Those IP Ranges you are sharing are for the Compute services per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range)

I do not recall (and can not find at the moment) that exists such lists for the storage services on GCP.

But perhaps you can try to add a load balancer in front of the GCP Bucket? In this case you can whitelist the IP of the load balancer. [This documentation might help](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets)

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion. However this would cost extra.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses#outbound-ip-addresses). This list is for google API endpoints, not restricted to storage service. You can take the IPs from [goog.json](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json) and subtract the IPs from [cloud.json](https://cloud.json) to get the google APIs IPs. They can change so you need to retrieve them periodically.

```
import requests
import ipaddress

def get_ipv4_ranges(url):
    """Fetches IPv4 ranges from a given URL."""
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        return {prefix['ipv4Prefix'] for prefix in data['prefixes'] if 'ipv4Prefix' in prefix}
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data from {url}: {e}")
        return set()

def sort_ipv4_ranges(ranges):
    """Sorts IPv4 ranges."""
    return sorted(ranges, key=lambda ip: ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip))

def main():
    # URLs containing the IPv4 ranges
    goog_url = "https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json"
    cloud_url = "https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json"

    # Fetching the IPv4 ranges
    goog_ipv4_ranges = get_ipv4_ranges(goog_url)
    cloud_ipv4_ranges = get_ipv4_ranges(cloud_url)

    # Removing the cloud ranges from the goog ranges and sorting
    remaining_ranges = sort_ipv4_ranges(goog_ipv4_ranges - cloud_ipv4_ranges)

    # Output the sorted remaining ranges
    for range in remaining_ranges:
        print(range)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```